# How can I get past Gmail's "Printing not yet available" short of waiting indefinitely?

Tags: gmail

I sometimes receive an PDF attachment where Print is blocked by:

[image]

If I wait an indefinite period of time, this resolves, in that Print becomes available.

When I can't afford to wait, how can get past this? Currently I can only download and print from disc.

Comment: [Edit] the question to include additional details.  What browser are you using?  Is the behavior similar in other browsers?  Have you tried it in private mode with extensions disabled? Can another user replicate the problem?  What are the specific steps to replicate?   Is this an intermittent problem that can't be replicated on demand? Is there anything common/uncommon to the PDFs that  work/don't work? If this is a printer/browser-specific problem or requires troubleshooting related to your PC's settings it may be a better fit on [su].

Comment: You've evidently misunderstood the point of the question. It is not to debug the issue, or to details it to someone insufficiently knowledgeable to answer it. It is to find an answer from a user who has experienced the issue and knows a solution. For such a user, the details already given are more than sufficient.

Comment: I appreciate your clarification.  Even if the question quality is the result of a strategic choice rather than an oversight, it is not in keeping with our site goals.  Please take the [Tour] and review [ask].

Comment: The point is to *"find an answer from a user who has experienced the issue "*  Note that high-rep users on this and other SE sites more often than not provide solutions to problems they haven't actually experienced.  They use their domain knowledge, experience, and understanding of the types of details needed.  It seems misguided to refuse to share information or to be the arbiter of what is or isn't useful to those seeking to help you.  Especially in the context of a problem you admittedly lack the domain knowledge and experience to solve yourself.

Comment: I voted to reopen, the question looks fine to me. Chris, you can also vote to reopen since you have over 500 of rep.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a solution for it.  The pdf has not been downloaded to your browser (the session's storage).

- You can still download it because you are downloading it from the source.
- You can view it in the browser because yet again, it is fetched from the source.
- But printing requires that the pdf has already been downloaded.  So you have to wait for this asynchronous activity to finish.